# Why can't the wave function and it's derivative be zero at the same point?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

This was discussed before proving the node theorem.

Comment: This was discussed before where?

Answer (score 1):

The 1D [TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) is a second-order homogeneous [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation). The complete solution span a 2-dimensional vector space parametrized by 2 constants. It is not hard to see that if a solution and its derivative vanish in the same point, it must be the zero-solution. The zero-solution is unacceptable as a wave-function.

Comment: I could not imagine a counterexample so I buy it.